# Spring-boot actuator health page works differently in Spring-boot project than in Grails project

Tags: spring-boot, grails, spring-boot-actuator

I've installed spring actuator in some of my rest-api projects, to monitor their operation but one thing caught my attention.

After I installed actuator in one of my spring boot rest-api project, when accessing actuator/health address it responded this.

```
{
status: "UP",
components: {
db: {
status: "UP",
details: {
database: "Microsoft SQL Server",
validationQuery: "isValid()"
}
},
diskSpace: {
status: "UP",
details: {
total: 50432839680,
free: 35323191296,
threshold: 10485760,
exists: true
}
},
mail: {
status: "UP",
details: {
location: "mail.company.com.br:25"
}
},
ping: {
status: "UP"
},
rabbit: {
status: "UP",
details: {
version: "3.8.9"
}
}
}
}
```

On the other hand, when I installed it in two of my Grails 3 / Grails 4 projects, it responded only this:

```
{
status: "UP",
details: {
diskSpace: {
status: "UP",
details: {
total: 50432839680,
free: 12816162816,
threshold: 10485760
}
}
}
}
```

I would like to learn how to make the Grails 3/4 responses be similar (with the same relevant information) as the Spring boot project does by default.

Could you help me?

Below, it is how actuator is configured in my Grails project, build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {                
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"        
}
```

Thanks

Alfredo Oliveira

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with the fact that Grails uses a very different configuration. For example, Grails does not use the @RestController or @requestmapping annotations and instead uses a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping (in 2.0) and a UrlMappingsHandlerMapping (in 3.0)

see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/77843bd857d3718d439e264b013eb566fc3afd32/grails-test-suite-uber/src/test/groovy/org/grails/web/plugins/support/web-interceptor-wiring-tests.xml

2.x version of handler mapping: https://github.com/thornjad/grails-2.4.2/blob/a20d11f66e3a0437e8deac43e7065046d59edc91/grails-web-mvc/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsUrlHandlerMapping.java

3.X version of handlermapping : https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/77843bd857d3718d439e264b013eb566fc3afd32/grails-web-url-mappings/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/mapping/mvc/UrlMappingsHandlerMapping.groovy